# JavaFX How not to passed event to a parent

Tags: javafx

I have Pane with:

```
pane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventsHandler(e -> System.out.println(""), e -> { 
     createEvents(e.getX(), e.getY());
})});
```

And method createEvents:

```
Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, 5);
circle.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> System.out.println("Clicked!"));
pane.getChildren().add(circle);
```

When I click in a circle, it calls two events: the string click and create a new event. How do you not passed click event to a parent?

My EvendsHandler add pane:

```
public class EventsHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> onDraggedEventHandler;
    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> onClickedEventHandler;

    private boolean dragging = false;

    public EventsHandler(EventHandler<MouseEvent> onDraggedEventHandler, EventHandler<MouseEvent> onClickedEventHandler) {
        this.onDraggedEventHandler = onDraggedEventHandler;
        this.onClickedEventHandler = onClickedEventHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            dragging = false;
        } else if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED) {
            dragging = true;
        } else if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
            // maybe filter on dragging (== true)
            onDraggedEventHandler.handle(event);
        } else if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
            if (!dragging) {
                onClickedEventHandler.handle(event);
            }}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using event filters. Filters are called while traversing from the root to the target node. Since all filters of the ancestors are called before a node's own filter is called it's impossible for the node's filter to prevent the execution of the parent's filter.

You should use event ***handlers*** instead which are called while traversing from the target node to the root node and allow you to prevent execution of the parent's event handlers by consuming the event:

```
pane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventsHandler(e -> System.out.println(""), e -> { 
     createEvents(e.getX(), e.getY());
})});
```

```
circle.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
    System.out.println("Clicked!");
    event.consume();
});
```

**Note:** If you only register a single event handler for a specific event type you can assign e.g. the `onMouseClicked` property instead of using `addEventHandler`:

```
circle.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    System.out.println("Clicked!");
    event.consume();
});
```

Comment: I need to use a filter for events called in the pane because the click creation of a new event while dragging the change of its location.

Comment: @Light I don't get it. Unless you consume the event it will be triggered for the event. "Click generation" happens independent from the handlers: When you release the mouse, javafx checks, if this qualifies as a click and triggers the regardless of the result of event handlers/filters that are previously run. There simply is no way of stopping the event filter's execution. (Similar to the impossibility of preventing `m1` from executing by throwing an exception from `m2` in the following code: `m1();m2();`)

Comment: if i add pane.setOnMouseClicked and i add to chilldren circle.setOnMouseClicked and I will click on circle and I will call all events (pane and circle) . I turn off filter and set only listener setOnMouseClicked.

Comment: Ok - only need to e.consume(); - It stops the passed of events up :) Thanks